# OOP design for deletion of an object with many dependent objects

Tags: oop

I would like to know a best way to design a deletion of an object, with triggers deletion of many dependent objects.

Here is an example. There is an Employer class. When an employer is deleted, all its jobs, invoices are deleted. When a job is deleted its category selection is deleted as well. And so on. So as you can see deletion of Employer triggers deletion on many more objects. The problem is that I have to pass many arguments required for deletion of dependent objects to the delete method in the Employer class.

Here is a simplified example. Imagine a class Main. When a Main object is deleted, objects Dep1, Dep2 have to be deleted as well. When Dep1 is deleted, Dep11 has to be deleted as well. If delete methods look like this: Dep1.delete(arg1), Dep2.delete(arg2), Dep11.delete(arg3), then the delete method on Main has to look like this: Main.delete(arg1, arg2, arg3). You see? The more objects depend on the Main - more arguments will be needed for deletion.

I must also point out that I am interested in deletion from the database, i.e. deletion in its "business logic" sense. I do not even unset "deleted" objects in the delete method.

What options I have considered:

- grouping arguments required for deletion into a separate object. I just do not see how all these arguments can be grouped. They simply do no belong together. For example if an Invoice_searcher and Job_searcher are needed - why would they go together in one object? And what object could that be?
- moving deletion of dependent objects out of the delete method in the Employer class. In this case not calling delete methods on children explicitly would leave the system in an inconsistent state. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question but Udi Dahan has posted an excellent blog on the term "delete": http://www.udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/

Comment: That's an interesting point of view, but does not solve my problem and discussing "not deleting" is out of this question's context.

Comment: What kind of arguments are required for deletion of dependent objects? `object.deleteYourself()` seems like a fairly straightforward instruction that shouldn't require any other input.

Comment: What I mean by that is, shouldn't the objects themselves have all the information they need to delete themselves?

Comment: like, I wrote in the question, for example: employer.delete(job_searcher, invoice_searcher, ...). In other words I have to pass objects (searchers) that are needed for retrieval of dependent objects.
Also some cache storage objects could be passed in order to remove deleted entities from there as well.

Comment: If the object is deleted, you can try to use a **destructor** to determine what would happen once the object is destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing parameters to deletion functions, you are making a mistake.

Each *object* on which you call your deletion function should be able to identify the other *objects* which it is the parent of.

I emphasise *object* because it sounds like you are coming at this from a relational perspective.

Comment: I suppose this could be the right answer for the situation. MrMisterMan suggested the same in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Composition in such a way that once u make the employee reference less other will become automatically reference less....

Other way is to take the help of nested class , if the top most encapsulating class will get
unreferenced other will also be automatically get unreferenced..(but make sure u are not pulling out the reference of nested class(say your inner class) out in some other class.)

Comment: Perhaps, I should have made it clear that the problem is with deleting objects from the database, i.e. from the business logic domain, not unsetting objects themselves.

Answer (score 0):

In my line of work I don't have to write much code to delete, so take my advice with a grain of salt. It might help to look at how these objects/records are created, and handle the deletion in the same way. For example, if the create logic is like this:

1. Create Employer
2. Create Invoice
3. Associate Invoice with Employer

than maybe the delete logic should look like this:

1. Remove Associations of Invoice(s) with Employer
2. Delete Invoice(s)
3. Delete Employer

As long as the entities are created in a consistant way, deleting them in the reverse order should also prove to be consistant.

Comment: The problem is that an employer can be created without an invoice, invoice is created separately any time, and not from an employer object.
But deletion must happen from employer.
I know how deletion should go. The problem here is too many arguments for deletion of entities that depend on the main parent (employer)

Comment: If the Invoice is created independantly of the Employer object, why not delete it independently of the Employer object? I think it is the requirement that the Employer must be responsible for deleting, but not for creating the Invoice (and the other Children) that makes this different from what I usually encounter. But if that requirement is truely a requirement, I don't think there's anything you can do except to tell the Employer which objects must be deleted (by passing all the arguments).

Comment: Deleting employer and invoices independently (using different methods) would leave a possibility for the system to be in an inconsistent state (invoices not belonging to any employers)